# Am I able to nickname my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just caught my first Pokemon, but I did not see any option to give my Pokemon a name. Is there any way I am able to nickname my Pokemon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can rename a Pokemon at any time after catching it, it doesn't have to be directly afterwards.

1. From the main (map) view, click the Pokéball, and go to Pokémon.
2. Click on the Pokémon you want to rename.
3. Rename the Pokémon by clicking on the name field.

They can be renamed as many times as you want.

Comment: Ah ha! I see that now. The edit icon appeared very faint on my screen and missed it on first glance

Comment: Can you rename it more than once? Since I just wanted to translate their names but evolving would be a problem then

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Yes. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Do others see the renamed pokemon if i put it in an arena? How do they prevent players picking rude names?

Comment: @Gigala I haven't yet seen any other nicknames other than my own so I can't say definitely one way or the other. No idea how they prevent it (if they even do)

Comment: Don't forget you can use html tags to make the name bold or italic etc